# PHP request database

Tags: php, database

I am blocked on a hard request to my database in php....

I would lik to display on my page a list the 10 persons (name/surname) that :
- have answered "1" to 3 questions (question1/question2/question3)
- and have answered at the question4 the closest number of participations (positive or negative sens)

Well i know how to determine my global number of paticipation :

```
$query_count = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Nb FROM my_table";    
$result_count = mysql_query($query_count) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_count)){
    echo "Participations :  ". $row['Nb'];
    echo "<br />";
    $count = $row['Nb']; // i create a $count var for next steps
```

Then i know how to display a request in table :

```
$query = "SELECT id,name,surname FROM my_table ORDER BY id"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);


// Recuperation des resultats
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        $id = $row[0];
        $name = $row[1];
        $surname = $row[2];



        echo "<tr>\n
        <td>$id</td>\n
        <td>$name</td>\n
        <td>$surname</td>\n
        </tr>\n";

    }
```

But in my $query i don't know how to say :
show the 10 row WITH name,surname AND answer=1 to question1,2and3 AND 
question4 is closer to number of participations (less, equal or more)

Do you have an idea?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your question is elementary: `WHERE answer IN (1,2,3)` after you make the appropriate join.   Since I don't have your full schema I can't help with specifics, but here is a rough example:

> SELECT u.user_name_first, u.user_name_last FROM user u LEFT JOIN
>   answers a ON u.user_id = a.user_id WHERE a.answer_id IN (1,2,3);

The second half is vague.   Please clarify what you mean by "closer to number of participations (less, equal or more)".

Comment: Thanks I mean the 4th question of my quizz is "how many participations will we have with the contest?" So thoses (10 persons) who will answer a number the closest to the global number of participation will win. it could be more, equal or less to the global number of participations...

Comment: What happens when 20 people guess the exact number of participants?  How are you deciding who gets the ax?

Comment: if multiple exact numbers, sort by id (subscription date)